# Chartjs barchart group dataset by label

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to create a grouped barchart graph but looks like there is no built in solution for it on chartjs, has anybody such experience before with grouping dataset by label, please check screenshot

[chart trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZeSo.png)

Idea is to have 4 different datasets with at least 4 data each and show in graph grouped.

Trying to achieve this with latest chartjs but I'm open to change it if there's easy way to do it with different library.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this using chartjs? Our organization is looking for the same solution

Comment: you can find it implemented here https://www.swissauditmonitor.ch/report-2020/ in section 3, it wa long time ago so I don't recall exact customization I did to chartjs but js shouldn't be obfuscated so you can reverse engineer. @ScottClark

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the feature request you're looking for(I think).

[Chartjs Feature Request for data grouping](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4053)

Here is a link to [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart).

I did a little digging scrolling through their demos and it looks like they do what you're looking for.